# Laravel on XAMPP not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using XAMPP for on my local machine and everything's working fine, 
I tried to install Laravel in my local machine id didn't work on XAMPP! 
I tried `php artisan serve` it worked perfectly fine ! 
what am I missing ?

Comment: Please describe your error. How did you install laravel on xampp. Did you setup a vhost - did you set it up for localhost directly. What error do you see?

Comment: FrankProvost  I don't get anything the page was blank and I did everything correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which version of php XAMPP uses ? the minimum required version is

PHP >= 5.6.4
Laravel Official Website

The default version of XAMPP's PHP framework is 5.6.30